# html footer with css

Tags: html, css, css-float, footer

i have the following problem:

i would like to create a footer. that footer should look like:

```
text headline           link 1    |    link 2    |    link 3
```

my thoughts were to use a div as container. in html i still dont know what to use. would it be better to realize that by using dl or ul?

so i did it by dl with the following html:

```
<div id="footer">
      <dl>
        <dt>text headline</dt>
        <dd>link 1</dd>
        <dd>link 2</dd>
        <dd>link 3</dd>
      </dl>
  </div>
```

for css:

```
#footer {
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 1200px;
}
#footer dl {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
#footer dl dd {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

the problem is that i dont know how to add the hyphens. another problem is that the headline is positioned ahead the links. here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fFddz/2/

so if there is someone who could help me out, i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Comment: Is that even valid HTML? Mutliple `dd`'s and one `dt`?

Comment: yes it is. the dt is just an headline for the subordered links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want the hyphens. This is the best I can do.
http://jsfiddle.net/fFddz/9/

If you could live without I would write the following.

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
<ul>
    <li><a>...</a></li>
    <li><a>...</a></li>
    <li><a>...</a></li>
    ....
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer div{
      /**what you already have***/
}

/**Makes the items appear in a line. But you can't define the width of an inline element.**/
#footer li{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}

#footer a{
    display:block; /**Allows you to define a width.*//
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<div id="footer">
      <ul>
        <li>text headline</li>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

for your mark up, and

```
footer {
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 400px;
}


#footer li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
     list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

for your css

Comment: He said that he does not want to use ul lists

Answer (score 0):

You can use ul for this below is working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fFddz/5/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a border in combination with the `:first-child` pseudo selector to restrict it to all but the first elements.

```
#footer dl dd {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}

#footer dl dd:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I can think of which will work across almost all the browsers is using the following styles:

```
#footer dl {
    display: inline-block;
}
#footer dt {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
#footer dl dd {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: solid 1px #000;
}
#footer dl dd.last {
    border: none;
}
```

And with these styles you can use the following HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <dl>
        <dt>text headline</dt>
        <dd>link 1</dd>
        <dd>link 2</dd>
        <dd class="last">link 3</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/sarcastyx/Dbh9H/

Comment: you don't need to set display:block with float:left, float property makes element 'block' automatically

Comment: @yarm, interesting. I think I was always doing that since my IE6 days. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

i want suggest you to put links in one `<dd>` then you will be able to use pseudo-selector `:first-child` for first link to hide left border

for `dt` and `dd` set `float:left` to make it in one line and for `dl` set `overflow: hidden` to clear floats

html

```
    <div id="footer">
      <dl>
        <dt>text headline</dt>
        <dd>
            <a href="">link1</a>         
            <a href="">link2</a>         
            <a href="">link3</a>         
        </dd>
      </dl>
  </div>
```

css

```
footer {
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 500px;
}
#footer dl {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;            
}
#footer dt {
    float: left;
}
#footer dd {
    float: left;
}
#footer dd a {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    *display: inline; zoom: 1;    
    position: relative;
}
#footer dd a:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fFddz/11/

Answer (score 0):

Hey have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/fFddz/13/

Changed html structure to UL and changed css.